# React useContext: how to update a context in a child component without making the parent component re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-context

i am working on an React app using the React Hooks especially the useContext Hook witch is important.

My context are listed like this:

```
import React, {useState, useReducer, createContext} from 'react';


export const AllContext = createContext();

export const ContextController = (props) =>
{
    const [IDArray,setIDArray] = useState([]);

    const [refreshSensorMenu, setRefreshSensorMenu] = useState(false);
    const [composantSensorData, setComposantSensorData] = useState([
        {id:"78320c5b-494c-4538-ae9f-36e28009e9f1",name:"Test1 - Test1",dateCreation: "04/04/2021",configuration:{
            manufacturer: "Test1",
            model: "Test1",
            type: "acceleration",
            unit: "m/s2",
            signal_conversion: "Factor and Offset",
            factor: "5",
            offset: "4"
        },eventKey:"0",isActive: true}
    ]);
    const [refreshProjectMenu, setRefreshProjectMenu] = useState(false);
    const [composantProjectData, setComposantProjectData] = useState([
        {id:"28360c5b-600c-4538-he9f-36e45689e9f1",name:"Test1",dateCreation:"16/03/2021",dateLastSave:"16/03/2021",configuration:{
            name:"Test1",
            customer:"Bob",
            machine:[
                {
                    id: "28360n5b-444c-4538-ar9f-36e28009e9f1",
                    isActive: true,
                    isValid: true,
                    kinematic_frequencies: "TEst1",
                    location: "TEst1",
                    manufacturer: "TEst1",
                    model: "TEst1",
                    name: "Machine1"
                }
            ],
            edge:[
                {
                    id: "28360y5b-494i-4538-ak9f-36a28009e9f1",
                    data_retention: 1,
                    isActive: true,
                    isValid: true,
                    name: "Edge0",
                    periods: 120,
                    vibrations_analysis: [],
                    simple_statistics_analysis: [],
                    device:[
                        {
                            id:"28348y5b-594i-4538-ak9f-36a48109e9f1",
                            description: "Nice description",
                            interface: "gantnerQStation",
                            ip_address: "124.100.100.20",
                            isActive: true,
                            isValid: true,
                            activated:true,
                            name: "Device 0",
                            port: "25655",
                            processing_timeout: "5",
                            sampling_duration: "10",
                            sampling_frequency: "18",
                            trigger_address: "23",
                            trigger_name: "trigger",
                            channel:[
                                {
                                    data_conversion_managed_by_device: true,
                                    id: "28860y5b-782i-4538-aq9f-36a28009e9f1",
                                    isActive: true,
                                    isValid: true,
                                    machine: "28360n5b-444c-4538-ar9f-36e28009e9f1",
                                    name: "Channel1",
                                    offset: "5",
                                    resolution: "5",
                                    sensor: "78320c5b-494c-4538-ae9f-36e28009e9f1",
                                    type: "acceleration",
                                    variable_index: "3"
                                },
                                {
                                    data_conversion_managed_by_device: true,
                                    id: "84260y5b-782i-1236-aq9f-36a28009e9f1",
                                    isActive: true,
                                    isValid: true,
                                    machine: "28360n5b-444c-4538-ar9f-36e28009e9f1",
                                    name: "Channel4",
                                    offset: "5",
                                    resolution: "5",
                                    sensor: "78320c5b-494c-4538-ae9f-36e28009e9f1",
                                    type: "acceleration",
                                    variable_index: "3"
                                }                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, eventKey:"0",isActive:true},
        {id:"48260y5b-782i-8436-aq9f-36a28119e9a1",name:"Test2",dateCreation:"16/03/2021",dateLastSave:"16/03/2021",configuration:{name:"Test2",customer:"Tektiv",edge:[],machine:[]}, eventKey:"1",isActive:true}
    ]);
    const [projectIndexConfiguration, setProjectIndexConfiguration] = useState(0);
    const [edgeIndexConfiguration, setEdgeIndexConfiguration] = useState(-1);
    const [deviceIndexConfiguration, setDeviceIndexConfiguration] = useState(-1);

    const [refreshWindowConfiguration, setRefreshWindowConfiguration] = useState(false);
    const [refreshMachineConfiguration,setRefreshMachineConfiguration] = useState(false);
    const [refreshEdgeConfiguration,setRefreshEdgeConfiguration] = useState(false);
    const [refreshSimpleStatisticsAnalysisConfiguration, setRefreshSimpleStatisticsAnalysisPathConfiguration] = useState(false);
    const [refreshVibrationAnalysisConfiguration,setRefreshVibrationAnalysisConfiguration] = useState(false);
    const [refreshDeviceConfiguration,setRefreshDeviceConfiguration] = useState(false);
    const [refreshChannelConfiguration,setRefreshChannelConfiguration] = useState(false);

    const [partCreated, setPartCreated] = useState({created:true,partName:""});
    const [componentCreated, setComponentCreated] = useState({created:false,componentName:""});
    const [tabConfigEnabled, setTabConfigEnabled] = useState({enabled:false,componentType:""});

    const [refreshPathConfiguration, setRefreshPathConfiguration] = useState(false);


    return (
        <AllContext.Provider value={{
            id: [IDArray,setIDArray],
            menu: 
            {
                project: 
                {
                    refresh: [refreshProjectMenu, setRefreshProjectMenu],
                    component:
                    {
                        data: [composantProjectData, setComposantProjectData]
                    }
                },
                sensor:
                {
                    refresh: [refreshSensorMenu, setRefreshSensorMenu],
                    component:
                    {
                        data: [composantSensorData, setComposantSensorData]
                    }
                }

            },
            configuration:
            {
                index:
                {
                    project: [projectIndexConfiguration, setProjectIndexConfiguration],
                    edge: [edgeIndexConfiguration, setEdgeIndexConfiguration],
                    device: [deviceIndexConfiguration, setDeviceIndexConfiguration]

                },
                window:
                {
                    refreshWindow: [refreshWindowConfiguration, setRefreshWindowConfiguration],
                    refreshMachine: [refreshMachineConfiguration,setRefreshMachineConfiguration],
                    refreshEdge: [refreshEdgeConfiguration,setRefreshEdgeConfiguration],
                    refreshSimpleStatisticsAnalysis: [refreshSimpleStatisticsAnalysisConfiguration, setRefreshSimpleStatisticsAnalysisPathConfiguration],
                    refreshVibrationsAnalysis: [refreshVibrationAnalysisConfiguration,setRefreshVibrationAnalysisConfiguration],
                    refreshDevice: [refreshDeviceConfiguration,setRefreshDeviceConfiguration],
                    refreshChannel: [refreshChannelConfiguration,setRefreshChannelConfiguration]

                },
                component:
                {
                    part: [partCreated, setPartCreated],
                    created: [componentCreated, setComponentCreated],
                    tab: [tabConfigEnabled, setTabConfigEnabled]
                },
                path:
                {
                    refresh: [refreshPathConfiguration, setRefreshPathConfiguration]
                }
            }
        }}>
            {props.children}
        </AllContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And the ContextController is like this:

```
export default function App(props)
{
    return (
        <StylesProvider injectFirst>
            <ContextController>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Box} />
                </Switch>
            </ContextController>
        </StylesProvider>
    )
};
```

I have some questions about how the Context hook renders the components.
I thought that a **component only render when the context witch he is subscribe update.**
But it doesn't seem the case for exemple when i change have a parent component only subscribe to the context named **part**, father of a child component subscribe to the context named **created**.

When i update the context **created**, it does re-render the child component witch make sense but also re-render the parent component witch is a problem.
Because if a component like a SnackBar change a context when opening and closing it will refresh the parent component, that mean if you're are doing some work in a form from a modal while the SnackBar still open, when the snackBar auto close, it will make a refresh of the parent component that lead to reappear the form and destroy all of your edit.

This might be not big but for an app for configuration of files so 90% of form this little thing can be annoying.
I thought maybe it is because the 2 contexts are in the same object named **component** that cause to change the objet itself so re-render all components subscribe to the object.
But it still re-render the parent component when i make the context not in the object **component**.

Some explanation will be gladly taken.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason is whenever there is  a change in any of the state you are creating a new object on the fly because of this value={{} <-- new object each time } . And due to this change in value all the components subscribed to your contexts will re-render even if you are reading only part of it .

Comment: But if a component is subscribe to one of 2 context and the other update, the component can't be re-render right?

Comment: Consider you have 2 contexts A and B and you parent is subscribed to A and your child is subscribed to B . Now if your context A changes , your parent component will render which will by default trigger a re-render for child component even though child is subscribed to context B . But if the components subscribing your contexts are siblings then change in one should not affect the other .

Comment: And if i make the child component change B, it shouldn't re-render the parent component. right?

Comment: yes that is correct !

Comment: Just to be sure, by two context you mean two data inside a context or two context created by createContext() ?